# Hide a <li> item class

Tags: css, hide

I want to hide this bit: `<li class="categories">Kατηγορίες<ul>` as seen in the code below (also see here https://poiimata.com/poets/):

```
<li class="categories">Kατηγορίες<ul>   
<li class="cat-item cat-item-123">
    <a href="https://poiimata.com/category/robert-frost/" >Robert Frost</a>
</li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-124">
    <a href="https://poiimata.com/categoryshlain-goldberg/" >Shlain</a>
</li>
```

I tried using

```
.categories {
  display:none;  
}
```

but the result was to hide all items below that one (the whole list).

Comment: So, you just want to hide the word "Kατηγορίες"?

Comment: Of course it does if it's nested inside the li.

Comment: Yes, just that word really.

Answer (score 3):

That happen because you've an invalid HTML code in :

```
<li class="categories">Kατηγορίες<ul>
_________________________________^^^^
```

The browser will evaluate your code to the below format, that why all your li's become hidden :

```
<ul>
    <li class="categories">Kατηγορίες
       <ul>
          <li class="cat-item cat-item-123"><a href="https://poiimata.com/category/robert-frost/">Robert Frost</a>
          </li>
          <li class="cat-item cat-item-124"><a href="https://poiimata.com/categoryshlain-goldberg/">Shlain</a>
          </li>
       </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Instead it should be :

```
<ul>
  <li class="categories">Kατηγορίες</li>
  <li class="cat-item cat-item-123"><a href="https://poiimata.com/category/robert-frost/">Robert Frost</a>
  </li>
  <li class="cat-item cat-item-124"><a href="https://poiimata.com/categoryshlain-goldberg/">Shlain</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Snippet:

```css
.categories {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="categories">Kατηγορίες</li>
  <li class="cat-item cat-item-123"><a href="https://poiimata.com/category/robert-frost/">Robert Frost</a>
  </li>
  <li class="cat-item cat-item-124"><a href="https://poiimata.com/categoryshlain-goldberg/">Shlain</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I dont know. may be this is not bug, this is a feature? )

Comment: There's no invalid HTML, it's simple nesting like creating a sub-menu.

Comment: Then why posting the question, if he know that the `li` contain ither li's ? when you open the tag you should close it else the browser will do.

Comment: Because he probably doesn't understand the behavior, the expected outcome.

Comment: The code is generated by this Wordpress plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/list-categories/ I simply used 
`[categories orderby=name child_of=43]`

Comment: Found the solution, I had to add the title_li:

`[categories orderby=name child_of=43 title_li='']`

Answer (score 0):

It appears you just have an error in your HTML. You use an incorrect closing tag and therefore hide the entire thing.

```
 <li class="categories">Kατηγορίες<ul>  <!--- closed <li> with <ul> --->
<li class="cat-item cat-item-123">
    <a href="https://poiimata.com/category/robert-frost/" >Robert Frost</a>
</li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-124">
    <a href="https://poiimata.com/categoryshlain-goldberg/" >Shlain</a>
</li>
```

Try instead:

```
<ul class="categories">
<li >Kατηγορίες<li> 
   <li class="cat-item cat-item-123">
    <a href="https://poiimata.com/category/robert-frost/" >Robert Frost</a>
   </li>
   <li class="cat-item cat-item-124">
    <a href="https://poiimata.com/categoryshlain-goldberg/" >Shlain</a>
   </li>

</ul>
```

and change CSS to

```
.categories:first-child {
 display:none;  
}
```

That's just one way of accomplishing it. There are quite a few different angles you can take.

Comment: There's no error and this is not a solution. Check the website and inspect the element. He just didn't include what he should when posting the question.

Answer (score -1):

Since `li` contains tags that you do not need to hide, you need to masked the hidden text. for example like this:

```css
.categories {
  font-size: .1%;
}

.categories ul {
  font-size: 100000%;
}
```

if only child elements is not a bug...